# Scatterplot graphs line correctly, but points along the line have flipped along y-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to produce a scatterplot using [this example](https://gist.github.com/thudfactor/6688739) of constraint relaxation.
Here's my [semi-working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RcD9QrV8JPg3quZkbhbH?p=preview).

The trouble I'm having is that I want to plot the points along the blue line. Instead, they're inverted along the y-axis.

The original code in the example actually had the axis flipped:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([6.6, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d[1] + 0 ;
})])
    .range([0, height]); //flip y
```

I unflipped it like so:

```
.range([height, 0]); //flip y
```

This made the blue line graph correctly, but not the points. I want the points (and labels, of course) to graph along the blue line as it appears in [my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RcD9QrV8JPg3quZkbhbH?p=preview). How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear how to operationalize this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to simplify all the x/y calculations using these two scales:

```
var xext = d3.extent(data, d => d[0]);
var sx = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(xext)
  .range([0, width])
  .nice();

var yext = d3.extent(data, d => d[1]);
var sy = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(yext)
  .range([height, 0]) // flip y-axis
  .nice();
```

Then the new dataPoints array can be created from the raw data, like so:

```
var lastYear = 2016;
var dataPoints = data.map(function(d, i) {
  dx = sx(d[0]);
  dy = sy(d[1]);
  return {
    x: dx,
    y: dy,
    label: lastYear - i,
    labelX: dx + 5,
    labelY: dy - 5
  };
});
console.log(dataPoints);
```

From this enhanced data structure, all of the lines, points, and labels are placed into the chart area...

```
// begin of drawing lines
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(d => d.x)
  .y(d => d.y)
  .interpolate("linear");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", line(dataPoints))
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
  .style("stroke-width", 2)
  .style("stroke", "steelblue")
  .style("opacity", 0.7)
  .style("fill", "none");


// Place the points
var viewPoints = points.selectAll("point").data(dataPoints);

viewPoints.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr({
    class: "point",
    cx: d => d.x,
    cy: d => d.y,
    r: 2
  });


// Place the labels
var viewLabels = labels.selectAll("label").data(dataPoints);

viewLabels.enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(d => d.label)
  .attr({
    class: "label",
    x: d => d.labelX,
    y: d => d.labelY
  });


// Place the lines. Lines use the point position
// for the x1,y1 and the label position for the x2,y2.
var viewLines = lines.selectAll("line").data(dataPoints);

viewLines.enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr({
    class: "line",
    x1: d => d.x,
    y1: d => d.y,
    x2: d => d.labelX,
    y2: d => d.labelY
  });
```

I didn't change any of the relax function code, but some of that could be simplified using similar techniques.

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want to do. I want the points (and labels, of course) to graph along the blue line as it appears in my Plunker.

Comment: Oops, sorry -- I read that wrong... I'll edit my answer. I've also updated plunkr at
http://plnkr.co/edit/I03IirF3zrKI7vG5m9h1?p=preview

Comment: If I wanted to deconflict the points' labels from the x axis by extending the domain of y axis (beyond the nearest rounded value of the largest y value), how would I do that? I'm not familiar with .nice, so the closest I've come is this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mb7L9QH6bQGHGtqdMyKx?p=preview